# CharIndex find a related word or similar

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to be able to type a word into the 'where' clause and it searches all the tables for that word or words that are similar can this be done

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR (200)
SET @Test = 'Red'

SELECT        H.Name, O.Name AS 'Owner', S.SilksName, T.Name AS 'Trainer'
FROM          Horse H
INNER JOIN Owner O on CHARINDEX(@Test,O.Name) <> 0 or
INNER JOIN Trainer T ON CHARINDEX(@Test,T.Name) <> 0 or
INNER JOIN Runners R ON Horse.Horse_Skey = Runners.Horse_Skey 
INNER JOIN Silks S ON CHARINDEX(@Test,S.SilksName) <> 0 or 
INNER JOIN Jockey J ON CHARINDEX(@Test,J.FirstName) <> 0

WHERE @Test = 'Red'
```

Comment: You are looking for "full text search in SQL Server". (Type those words into your search engine and hit the search button.)

Comment: WHERE @Test = '%Red%'

Comment: Hi Alpesh I get the following error message

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: Hi Klas, Can the full text search work in a dataset for SSRS?

Comment: @wafw1971 It should work on all tables that have a full text index. Haven't fiddled with it myself, so I really don't know that much.

Comment: Hi Klas I get the following error message:

Msg 7615, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
A CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate can only operate on one table or indexed view. Qualify the use of * with a table or indexed view name.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR (200)
SET @Test = 'Red'

SELECT        H.Name, O.Name AS 'Owner', S.SilksName, T.Name AS 'Trainer'
FROM          Horse H
inner JOIN Runners R ON Horse.Horse_Skey = r.Horse_Skey 
left JOIN Owner O on CHARINDEX(@Test,O.Name) <> 0 
left JOIN Trainer T ON CHARINDEX(@Test,T.Name) <> 0     
left JOIN Silks S ON CHARINDEX(@Test,S.SilksName) <> 0  
left JOIN Jockey J ON CHARINDEX(@Test,J.FirstName) <> 0
where   ( (O.Name is not null)  or  (T.Name is not null)   or   (S.SilksName is not null)   or   (J.FirstName is not null)  )
```

INNER JOIN  with tables that must be exist and left join with others , of course some condition in where clause may be need.
where clause condition is updated

Comment: Hi Kojtaba thanks for that but I still get the following error message:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "Horse.Horse_Skey" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "Runners.Horse_Skey" could not be bound.

Do you know why?

Comment: "Horse.Horse_Skey" could not be bound  , check your table design for field name spell checking .

Comment: Hi Mojtaba It seems to work in a fashion, it is bringing to many lines back for example when I put the word Fry it should return two rows but it is bringing back 8 what can I do